# incorporating all views into one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just wondering what the shorthand would be in Rails to do this (if any):

I have views/pages/ containing 5 html.erb files and they all use the same default layout.html.erb, with one yield statement in the middle of it (the standard setup).

Now I want one view that incorporates all 5 of those erb files above contiguously, one after the other, in place of the one existing yield statement in that same layout.html.erb.

What minimal changes would I make to the layout.html.erb to accomplish this.

(Rails Newbie - like it more than Django now).

---

Comment: These views probably belong to different actions. Do you want to execute action logic as well?

Comment: Actually those actions will no longer be accessed.

Comment: Also, could you describe your app a little bit. This seems like a totally insane thing to do, never heard of it. :)

Comment: All those views will be accessed from within one page via a jquery control, so they all need to be in the same page.  The details aren't important but if I could do the above, I could accomplish what I actually need to.

Comment: Can you explain the use case for the application for this?  Normally, a browser submits a url, the routing engine interprets that url into a controller action and a set of parameters.  Then, that controller action gets called, the code within executes, and a template (.html.erb) gets rendered that has the same name as the controller action.  So when you hit /pages/3, it hits the show action, and renders show.html.erb within your layout.  Do you want it to work outside of that process?

Comment: I know that with a collection of DB records you can render them all one after the other with one partial in one statement in the layout - that's sort of what I wanted, but with all the views in a directory.  Those views won't all be visible at once - the jquery control will manage visibility.  I will modify the link-tos to just invoke a js function to change view in the client.

Comment: If you're making database hits with your jquery, you'll still want to hit a controller action via ajax.  Then, your controller action can be configured to respond to js, and then return some js to the client.  Usually, you would have a div with a specific id that you can use a replace_html javascript call to load a different page.

Comment: THis is a sample app from Rails Tutorial that I am modifying that's all.

Comment: I'm not hitting the DB with this jquery - that was just an example.  I want one function that will iterate through all the views in a folder and render them one after the other in the layout.  That will enable me to do what I want actually (they're actually going into a UL which is what this control wants.)

Comment: I think the reason this sounds so strange to do is that each action/template supplies a different view of a resource.  index.html.erb is viewing a collection, show.html.erb is viewing a member, edit.html.erb is modifying a member, new.html.erb is creating a new member.  I don't understand what it would mean to have all of them on the same page.  But I could see wanting a few of them on the same page, like the index and the show, or the index and the new.  You can use partials as outlined below to do that.  Good luck!

Comment: Does this explain it  -  http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/#/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, 
  I see what you're saying.  Try this.  Have your file structure such that all the views for said controller are in one folder...

@controllers_views = Dir.glob("your/controllers/views/*.erb")

@controllers_views.each { |cv| puts cv }

Seems like that would work, I'm away from my dev box or I'd test it for you.

Hope that helps.

Good luck!

Comment: No offense, but I don't want to use anything called "glob", or mess directly with the file system. I did encounter the ActionController property "methods" which returns a list of *all* methods, including inherited ones, which amounts to several hundred.  If I could just retrieve those in the immediate class (i.e. the action methods) that would solve my problem.  I want to know how to do this the right way for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could always have a javascript that requests the sequential yields at a time interval as an ajax request.  Then just your target element change to reflect the updated information.

Alternatively load all 5 into different divisions, and have them revolve visibility, like a picture gallery.  CSS3 could pull this off.

http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/09/10-pure-css3-image-galleries-and-sliders/

Comment: I'm not going to have to mess with ajax at all.  Actually,if there were a function that said "find all the actions (or views or templates) associated with this controller and return them as an array" that would solve my problem as I could just iterate through that and render each one.  I could have already done this through copy and paste; instead I want the one rail function to do this, e.g. <%= controller.get_actions.each do |x| render x  %>